# pypcap support for python 2.7?

Tags: python, windows, scapy

I want to install Scapy on Windows using Python 2.7, but the required package pypcap doesn't support Python 2.7. Is there a patch or a workaround to be able to install pypcap on Python 2.7?

Comment: I'm not able to test this until afternoon but maybe works, look at the last comment in this post http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/issues/detail?id=27 all you have to do it's create a patch with a copy-paste of a text that it's show in the post, and type: patch > python27patch (or your file name).  Then python setup.py build, pythonsetup.py install. Good Luck and at night I'll test this solution.

Comment: @rob.alarcon I dont know which text they're talking about

Answer (score 7):

I built a pypcap extension for Python 2.7 Windows a couple of days ago. Mario Vilas has regrouped the whole that so you may find the installers over here then: http://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/quickpost-updated-impacketpcapy-installers-for-python-2-5-2-6-2-7/

Answer (score 1):

Read this, and follow the instructions: http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/issues/detail?id=27#c6

Comment: The link to the Python 2.7 patch has been deleted, on the above link.